# Vue: Computed properties to check offsetHeight of elements not updating

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a component that takes an array of 50 objects.

```
<template>
   <div v-for="(item,index) in items" ref="items" :key="index">
      //
   </div>

</template>

props: {
    items: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
}
```

I want to have the prop `items` checked for their `offsetHeight` so I made a computed property, grabbed the `items` by their `ref` and first tested it by returning just that.

```
computed: {
  allItems() {
    const all = this.$refs.items;
    return all;
  }
}
```

in VueTools , this shows an array of `HTMLDivElement`'s and works as expected if I use `allItems` in place of `items` in the template.

now I want to implement the check for `offsetHeight`:

```
computed: {
  allItems() {
    const all = this.$refs.items;
    return all.filter(x => {
       x.offsetHeight > 300;
    })
  }
}
```

but this shows the computed property now as `15` so it filtered them but when I change the window height, the offsetHeight in the UI change but the computed property shows `15` regardless.  Shouldn't this continuously show the current values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't this continuously show the current values?

No, because `HTMLElement.offsetHeight` is a native property that cannot be observed by Vue. An element's height can by changed by the browser at any time without Vue's knowledge. You have to use another means to respond to changes in an element's size, such as using [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) or listening to the [window resize event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event).

Vue 2's reactivity system works with *plain objects* only. See [Reactivity in Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) for more information.